# Type mismatch from partition in Scala (expected (Set[String]...), actual (Set[String]...) )

Tags: scala, collections

I have a partition method that creates tuple of two sets of string.

```
  def partition(i:Int) = {
    dictionary.keySet.partition(dictionary(_)(i) == true)
  }
```

I also have a map that maps integer to the return value from the partition method.

```
val m = Map[Int, (Set[String], Set[String])]()
for (i <- Range(0, getMaxIndex())) {
  m(i) = partition(i)
}
```

The issue is that I have type mismatch error, but the error message does not make sense to me.

[image]

What might be wrong?

This is the code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import scala.collection.{BitSet}

case class Partition(dictionary:Map[String, BitSet]) {
  def max(x:Int, y:Int) = if (x > y) x else y
  def partition(i:Int) = {
    dictionary.keySet.partition(dictionary(_)(i) == true)
  }
  def getMaxIndex() = {
    val values = dictionary.values
    (0 /: values) ((m, bs) => max(m, bs.last))
  }
  def get() = {
    val m = Map[Int, (Set[String], Set[String])]()
    for (i <- Range(0, getMaxIndex())) {
      m(i) = partition(i)
    }
    m
  }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using a mutable `Map`, otherwise with a `val` the statement `m(i) = ...` would not make sense. It is recommended to qualify mutable collections, either by using `mutable.Map`, or aliasing the import like `import collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}`. I suspect that you have the `Set` also mixed up between mutable and immutable? You should improve your question by making it self-contained (including your imports).

Comment: Also, to rule out a problem in the presentation-compiler—the error is just shown in the IDE, or does it actually occur when you compile your code? Is that Eclipse or IDEA? I know that IDEA often has these kind of wrong type errors in the presentation compiler, although they are correct code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile your example, the error is clear:

```
<console>:64: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (scala.collection.Set[String], scala.collection.Set[String])
 required: (scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], scala.collection.immutable.Set[String])
             m(i) = partition(i)
                             ^
```

Looking into the API, the `keySet` method of a mutable map does not guarantee that the returned set is immutable. Compare this with `keySet` on an immutable Map—it *does* indeed return an immutable set.

Therefore, you could either

- use an immutable `Map` and a `var`
- force the result of your `partition` method to return an immutable set (e.g. `toSet`)
- define the value type of your map to be `collection.Set` instead of `Predef.Set` which is an alias for `collection.immtuable.Set`.

---

To clarify these types, it helps to specify an explicit return type for your public methods (`get` and `partition`)